# How to build a static library link to a third_part static library using Android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries

I want to build a static library link to a third_part static library. And then provide the static library which I built to other people to use. But when others use my library, they found an error "undefined reference to 'Func1()'", "Func1()" is a function defined in the third_part static library. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

```
Here's my Android.mk:

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ThirdLib_Rebuild
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libThird.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ThirdLib_Rebuild
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyLib.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

ndk-build supports transitive dependencies, i.e. if you define a shared library or executable that depends on your MyLib module, then both libMyLib.a and libThird.a will be linked into it (if not, this is a bug, which NDK are you using exactly?).

However, you're not very clear about what you're doing when distributing your libraries to other people. For the record, you need to distribute *both* libraries to your users, because libMyLib.a does not include the code from libThird.a, the use of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in the MyLib module definition only serves to record a dependency between the two libs, unlike what happens when you use it for a shared library or executable.